# What is the main idea of using "do" with a verb in these sentences

Tags: expressions

I often come across the phrases like these:

> **do** make the change: e.g, "But do make the change I've posted, it is always good practice to use the variables names"
>
> **do** care about this: e.g, "I really do care about you as one of my best friend."

So what is the main idea of using "DO" in such a way?

Comment: It's very difficult to say without more context, because there are a number of ways the verb *to do* can be used.  Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples, "do" is an intensifier. It emphasizes the verb.